# Profiling ASP.NET Core / dotnet projects: Analysis failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am trying to set up a profiling session on my ASP.NET Core web application in Visual Studio 2015.

In the Performance Profiler, I am targeting 'Executable' and will use the performance wizard to configure the type of profiling (instrumentation, for example):

[image: Profiling Executable]

I then select the project I want to profile:

[image]

After finishing profiling, the report fails to load. In the performance output:

```
Profiling started.
Data written to C:\Product\MyProject\MyProject.Api160803(8).vsp.
Profiling finished.
File contains no data buffers
File contains no data buffers
Analysis failed
```

**Note:** I am targeting .NET 4.5.2 and NOT the core libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this happens because one of references does not have pdb file included.

Try to find pdb files, use sampling instead or remove such references.

I had similar issue as described at Microsoft's Forum post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d561480-c583-4144-9141-96d6517fcc6f